Bootstrap & My main Css Not Loaded When I use Jquery In Laravel
The first time you open the site, everything is done normally
But when I reload the page, Bootstrap & Css are loaded at the first moment, but then they disappear and this error appears in the console:
jquery.min.js:2   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)  jquery.min.js:2   GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/app.min.css 404 (Not Found)
My Code:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@yield('title') | Admin Portfolio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="Premium Multipurpose Admin & Dashboard Template" name="description" />
    <meta content="Themesdesign" name="author" />
    <!-- App favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('backend/assets/images/favicon.ico') }}">

    <!-- jquery.vectormap css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

    <!-- DataTables -->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Responsive datatable examples -->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/icons.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- App Css-->
    <link href="{{ asset('backend/assets/css/app.min.css') }}" id="app-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body data-topbar="dark">

    <!-- <body data-layout="horizontal" data-topbar="dark"> -->

    <!-- Begin page -->
    <div id="layout-wrapper">

        <!-- ========== Header ========== -->
        @include('admin.partials.header')
        <!-- End Header -->

        <!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->
        @include('admin.partials.left_sidebar')
        <!-- Left Sidebar End -->



        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <!-- Start right Content here -->
        <!-- ============================================================== -->
        <div class="main-content">

            <div class="page-content">
                @yield('content')
            </div>
            <!-- End Page-content -->

            <!-- Footer -->
            @include('admin.partials.footer')

        </div>
        <!-- end main content-->

    </div>
    <!-- END layout-wrapper -->

    <!-- ========== Right Sidebar ========== -->
    @include('admin.partials.right_sidebar')
    <!-- END Right-bar -->

    <!-- Right bar overlay-->
    <div class="rightbar-overlay"></div>

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/metismenu/metisMenu.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/simplebar/simplebar.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/node-waves/waves.min.js') }}"></script>


    <!-- apexcharts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- jquery.vectormap map -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/admin-resources/jquery.vectormap/maps/jquery-jvectormap-us-merc-en.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Required datatable js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- Responsive examples -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/libs/datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/js/pages/dashboard.init.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- App js -->
    <script src="{{ asset('backend/assets/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>

**When **I delete cookies, everything happens normally the first time I open the site
First Time Loaded This Page:
enter image description here
Second Time Loaded This Page:
enter image description here
*This extension Not the problem
